# removing namespaces in rootelement but retain the prefix in elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to remove all the namespaces in the rootelement but I need to retain the prefix in the elements? Is it possible to do it in xslt? For example, the xml look like this:

```
<c:RootElement xmlns:c="http://c.com" xmlns:s="http://s.com">
   <s:Element>543</s:Element>
   <s:Field>Sample</s:Field>
</c:RootElement>
```

And, I want the output like this:

```
<c:RootElement>
   <s:Element>543</s:Element>
   <s:Field>Sample</s:Field>
</c:RootElement>
```

Comment: What kind of output is that supposed to be? It would not be namespace well-formed XML so you could not create it using `xsl:element` or `xsl:copy`, you would need to create that markup as text. So are you sure you want/need that format?

Comment: yes, i need that format in my output. I just need to remove all the namespaces in the root element section. I don't know how to do it in xslt, so i don't have any idea if it is possible.

Comment: @pinkpanther I am quite sure you do NOT want to do that. If you remove the namespace declarations, you must remove the prefixes too.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output isn't namespace-well-formed XML, so it can't be produced using XSLT.

If you tell us why you want this, ie. what are you really trying to achieve by doing this, then perhaps we can suggest an alternative approach.